# How to fix this screwed part of Audio

Tags: audio, youtube, audio-quality

i am new to video production , and i know that audio is a big part of the production process and cannot be messed up .

here is a audio that i recorded and then reduced the noise from audacity and exported

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a5ZelYB6noyZhrVenkins0wZI62GC4Yj/view?usp=sharing

how can i further improve this audio

Answer (score 1):

Audio is not my expertise, i try my best.

The problems of your source are

1. volume is low
2. speech is fast
3. sound is dull
4. bass is insufficient
5. treble is high

Therefore,

1. I use the command to find the max volume

   `ffmpeg -i source.wav -af "volumedetect" -vn -sn -dn -f null /dev/null`
   , which is *-6.4dB*, then i transform the max volume to *0dB* by using `audio filter volume=6.4dB`
2. I slow down the speech by using `audio filter atempo=0.8`
3. I make it lively by using `audio filter aecho=0.06:0.9:50:0.7`
4. I boost the bass by using `audio filter firequalizer=gain_entry='entry(0,24);entry(250,12);entry(500,4);entry(1000,2);`
5. I decrease the treble by using `audio filter firequalizer=gain_entry='entry(4000,-4);entry(16000,-20)'`

In conclusion, the command is

```
ffmpeg -y -i source.wav -af "\
volume=6.4dB,\
atempo=0.8,\
aecho=0.06:0.9:50:0.7,\
firequalizer=gain_entry='\
entry(0,24);entry(250,12);entry(500,4);entry(1000,2);\
entry(4000,-4);entry(16000,-20)'" \
output.wav
```

Hope you like it, good luck.

Comment: I share the code https://colab.research.google.com/gist/xer-rex/fc1ea362f27699cfe2375d71332a0a10/audio_transform.ipynb

you can just do the playback on output.wav

Comment: i don't think that the audio has a lot of reverb or echo(idk the difference between reverb and echo) it would be helpful if you could check if it is same in your system. My desired result is something suitable for Youtube :)

Comment: The aecho document is https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aecho; it might help you get to the point of your "desired result", or not. I have no further comments on the subjectivity of hearing.